# How to handle multiple checkboxes in a PHP form?

Tags: php, html

I have multiple checkboxes on my form:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Cat" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Dog" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal" value="Bear" />
```

If I check all three and hit submit, with the following code in the PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
   echo $_POST['animal'];
}
```

I get "Bear", i.e. the last chosen checkbox value even though I picked all three. How to get all 3?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See the changes I have made in the name:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Cat" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Dog" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Bear" />
```

you have to set it up as array.

```
print_r($_POST['animal']);
```

Comment: PHP will throw an error if none of the checkboxes are checked, because `animal` will not even be set.

Answer (score 23):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Cat" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Dog" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Bear" />
```

If I check all three and hit submit, with the following code in the PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['animal'])){
    foreach($_POST['animal'] as $animal){
        echo $animal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use square brackets following the field name

```
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Cat" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Dog" />
<input type="checkbox" name="animal[]" value="Bear" />
```

On the PHP side, you can treat it like any other array.